# Normal distribution, easy question

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

I have a little doubt: if I have the following distribution $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma}(|x|-\mu)^2}$$
$1)$ can I say that it correspond to the $N(\mu,\sigma)$, also if I have |x| (but integral starting from $0$).

$2)$ for solving the integral how could I procede: I could start in this way
$$2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma}(x-\mu)^2} $$ but from here I can only deduce that the previous is $\le1$, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma}(|x|-\mu)^2} I_{x>0}$$ is the density of a normal random variable, it is not. This density vanishes on $(-\infty, 0)$ so it is not normal.

$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-\frac 1  {2\sigma} (x-\mu)^{2}}dx=\int_{-\mu}^{\infty} e^{-\frac 1  {2\sigma} x^{2}}dx$ which can be expressed in terms of the standard normal distribution function $\Phi (x)$: it is $\sqrt {\frac 2  {\pi}} [{1-\Phi(-\frac {\mu} {\sqrt \sigma})}]$.

Comment: I modified I little bit the question, try to give a look if you wish

Comment: @Alias__ It is still not normal.

Comment: what about question 2)

Comment: @Alias__ I have edited my answer.